# Why do my hyperlinks go to the wrong directory?

Tags: html

In my project functionality is like when i need to set a link to direct to:

```
/site/sales/sold.php
```

so the menu.php file link would look like this:

```
 <ul>
      <li><a href="sales/">Sales</a></li>   
      <li><a href="sold.php">Sold Items</a></li>
    </ul>
```

it would sometime direct to

```
/site/sales/sold.php
```

and the next moment, it repeats the menu's directory like:

```
/site/sales/sales/sold.php
```

so i removed the sales directory, as its directing there by itself, worked for a little while and now it directs to

```
/site/sold.php
```

which does not exist so it ends up with a 404.

Comment: Refer to the answer of the question you asked before, seem you have the slash in the wrong place.

Comment: Why do people always use all the available tags, instead of suitable tags?

Comment: @feeela Probably they feel this will result to more publicity, which it inevitably actually does.

Comment: @feeela Why didn't you remove them? :)

Comment: @Stijn I couldn't edit as there was an edit still pending…

Comment: @feeela There's an *Improve* button when there's a pending edit, you can use it to approve the edit and make your own at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a page `sales/` and link to a page `sales`, the link will result in `sales/sales/` – that is the defined behavior.

The default method to avoid that is to specify a base URL via the HTML `<base>` tag. There is no PHP, JS or CSS involved here – just good ol' HTML 2.0.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/site/">
```

Using this in your pages head, will define the given URL as base for all links on the page, thus a link like `sales/` will actually result in `http://www.example.com/site/sales/` when clicked.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use absolute Links? Or even URL-rewriting?

The only way of using relative links like your "sold.php" is if your menu only occurs inside your /sales directory. If this menu comes up for example inside a page on /site, of course it won't work, because there probably isn't a file called "sold.php" under /site/sold.php. So if you wan't to make sure, your link "Sold" always points to the right direction, use a Link like /site/sales/sold.php. Then it won't matter if you are inside /site or even inside /site/sales.

```
if i for example set my menu link to direct to: /site/sales/sold.php so the menu.php file link would look like this:

<li><a href="sales/">Sales</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="sold.php">Sold Items</a></li>
</ul>
```

This does not make sense. If you would point your link to /site/sales/sold.php, your link would look exactly like that: `<li><a href="/site/sales/sold.php">Sold Items</a></li>`